# I want to check the input string if it is a correct format

Tags: java, regex

I want to check the input string and validate if it is a correct number format  and have written the following regex.  `[+-]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*[e]?[+-]?[0-9]+.` but unfortunately it is outputting true for --6 or ++6

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        //Scanner
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        while(--t >= 0) {
            String string = in.nextLine();
            string = string.trim();
            //System.out.println(string);
            String regex = "[+-]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*[e]?[+-]?[0-9]+";
            //System.out.println(string.matches(regex));
            if(string.matches(regex)) {
                System.out.println(1);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I presume you're doing this for fun since you aren't using `Scanner` or using `Double.parseDouble()`.

Comment: Yeah just for fun...a simple but confusing number validation ! :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use this

`^[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?$`

Formatted

```
 ^ 
 [+-]? 
 (?:
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  
      \. \d+ 
 )
 (?: [eE] [+-]? \d+ )?
 $
```

Answer (score 2):

This is matching due to the second `[+-]?` in your regex string. In `++6 or --6`, it first matches the first `+-` since it is present, then again match the second `+-` since it was present, and then the digit.

But you were close. What you want to do is only match the second `[+-]?` if there is an exponent present. So just make the whole exponent part optional by enclosing in brackets and adding a `?` at the end. Like this, you will match the second `+-` only if there is an `e/E` in front of it.

```
^[+-]?([0-9]+)?[.]?[0-9]*([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?$
```

[image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rioDVk/4).

Comment: See i was adding brackets between the exponent part but they were square brackets and then I just gave up! Thank you you for the elaborate answer, really helped a lot!